# floating-number error. How to format the numbers?

Tags: ios, double, uilabel

I have got this weird bug were my number is really long like this:

[image: example]

I think it is so because i get it from a label.

```
Double(lblsSteppers[i].0.text!)!
```

I also seems to happen to only certain numbers like 9.2.

But i don't know a way to prevent it.
So does anybody also else have encountered this?
And what have they done to prevent it.

Update: 
The error that i got is floating-numbers of some sort.
So now somebody suggest to format the numbers for viewing them.
But how can i do that?

Comment: Floating point numbers can not represent 9.2 precisely - therefore you get the approximation displayed.

Comment: Yes i have the same error. thanks for the info. But i don't really how i can fix the error?

Comment: @Cing Apply formatting to the number, specifying the number of decimal places.

Comment: Can you tell me the function?